# Binary search gives incorrect output Java

Tags: java, binary-search

I'm having a problem with my code. We're working on binary search, and I can't seem to get the right output whenever I input a number. We were given a list of 60 numbers already in order(external file), and whatever number we input, the program should search and return the position. If the number is not on the list, it should return a -1.

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Prog489
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number to search for: ");
        int search = scan.nextInt();
        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Guest\\Documents\\java programs\\Prog489\\Prog489.in"));
        int[] num = new int[60];
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println(binarySearch(num, search));
        while(kbReader.hasNextInt())
        {
            num[i++] = kbReader.nextInt();
        }
    }

    private static int binarySearch(int[] num, int search)
    {
        int lb = 0;
        int ub = num.length - 1;
        while(lb<=ub)
        {
            int mid = (lb+ub)/2;
            if(num[mid] == search)
            {
                return mid;
            }
            else if(search>num[mid])
            {
                lb=mid+1;
            }
            else
            {
                ub = mid-1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

So the part with the return should only return -1 if the number is not on the list. But whenever I do enter a number on the list (such as 60), it still returns a -1. Everything compiles, so I'm not really sure what I'm missing, or if it's something really obvious that I'm forgetting. Could someone please help me identify the error? Any guidance/feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way to identify the error would be to use a debugger.

Comment: The first time you call `binarySearch`, you call it with a number array filled with zeroes... This is not what you want, is it?

Comment: Put your `System.out.println(binarySearch(num,search))` after you read in the input.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all responses. I realized that it was careless error on my part. Thanks again!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Debuggers are not panaceas. It most certainly depends on what tools are at your disposal. If you don't have a good user interface for working with the debugger, it would probably be easier to use some `println`s to see what's going on. Even with a debugger at my disposal, I often prefer that method, anyway, since the debuggers I've worked with are often unreliable or confusing things happen when the code is run (like the debugger pausing at an unexpected time with a different state and leaving me thinking something is wrong when it's not).

Comment: @user2989139 You will find that a significant portion (a majority, I would say) of yours bugs are caused by this. =)

Answer (score 2):

Move the call to print the output of `binarySearch` to **after** you populate the array:

```
int[] num = new int[60];
int i = 0;
while(kbReader.hasNextInt())
{
    num[i++] = kbReader.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(binarySearch(num, search));
```

Comment: I would only do that if you want to slow way down.  If the array has nothing in it, the search runs faster.

Comment: @CrazyDart Except it's not an "empty array"; it's an array of 60 default values (which should be zeros). So would it actually run any faster?